# How to handle flexible Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, flexible-array-member

## **Context**

So I've been playing around with arrays in C/ C++ trying to create arrays that 
could dynamically add and remove their elements.

Of course, I figured that the flexible array member feature in C would be the appropriate way to go. So I begun experimenting as the code below shows:

```
#include <cstdio> // printing stuff
#include <stdlib.h> // memory allocation stuff

// The array type
template <typename structType>
struct Array {
    private:
        // The structure containing the F.A.M.
        struct ArrayStructure { size_t length = 0; structType array[]; }
            *arrayStructurePointer, arrayStructure;
        constexpr inline static void add() {}

    public:
        // Constructor
        template <typename... types, typename = structType>
        explicit Array(types... elements) {
            this -> arrayStructurePointer =
                (ArrayStructure*) malloc(sizeof(structType));
            this -> arrayStructurePointer = &(this -> arrayStructure);
            this -> add(elements...);
        }

        // Destructor
        ~Array() {
            free(this -> arrayStructurePointer);
            free(this -> arrayStructure.array);
        }

        // Add stuff to the array
        inline void add(structType element) {
            this -> arrayStructurePointer =
                (ArrayStructure*) realloc(this -> arrayStructurePointer, sizeof(this -> arrayStructure));
            this -> arrayStructurePointer = &(this -> arrayStructure);
            this -> arrayStructure.array[this -> arrayStructure.length] = element;
            this -> arrayStructure.length += 1;
        }
        template <typename... types, typename = structType>
        inline void add(structType element, types... elements) {
            this -> add(element);
            this -> add(elements...);
        }

        // Query an element in the array
        constexpr inline structType operator [](size_t index) { return *(this -> arrayStructure.array + index); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Array<int> array(1, 0, 1);

    printf("Array [0]: %i\n", array[0]);
    printf("Array [1]: %i\n", array[1]);
    printf("Array [2]: %i\n", array[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

The point of this is for me to understand (possibly) how `vector`'s work and the challenges associated with it.

---

## **Problem**

I've only gotten as far as adding elements to the array but even with that,
as I compile and run the code there is this huge delay when the program ends before it exits (and I assume it's because of memory leaks).

---

## **Question**

So, the question: I want to assert that I'm following the right path in creating dynamic arrays that push & pop on request by asking how to even build dynamic arrays.

***How do I build dynamic arrays properly?*** OR

***How do I build my own*** `vector` ***structure?*** OR

***Are there any good resources/ PDFs out there that teach how dynamic arrays (or*** `vector`**'s) are made?**

Comment: Just use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) already. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Okay, there is no such thing as C/C++. The solution to your problem is different in C than it is in C++. Also, there is no "flexible array member" in C++. I suggest you take a different approach to tackling those two languages.

Comment: "C/C++" is not a thing. If you're using templates, that's definitely C++

Comment: Any reason you can't just use std::vector?

Comment: There's plenty wrong with the code you show.  You're (un)lucky it doesn't outright crash when it is run.

Comment: What you are trying to do is actually pretty tricky and explaining how to write such a class is likely too broad for an answer tbh. Dynamic allocation. Alignment. In-place construction/destruction. Reallocation (not using std::realloc)... rule of 5... etc... etc...

Comment: @Galik. Any good resources to check out, then? I'm trying to do this to understand how `std::vector`'s work.

Comment: It is a good exercise. Vectors are very efficient. They allocate chunks of memory and then manually construct the objects as and when needed. I mean you can examine the source code of the compiler's libraries because *std::vector* is a header only class so all the code is visible.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++ programs (as a general rule).

Comment: I would look up "rule of 3`, "rule of 5" and "rule of zero". Also "placement new" for a start.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `std::vector` for a variable-length array.  It solves this problem better and more reliably than your hand-rolled solution will in 999/1000 cases.

Comment: 999/1000? Are you sure it's that low?

Comment: Also the very important point that code using `std::vector` will be easily understood by other C++ programmers.

Comment: Alright then, let me re-phrase the question:
**How do I build my own** `std::vector` **?**

Comment: Also important is that compilers know how to optimise `std::vector` but they may fail to properly optimize your hand-rolled solution. Don't build you own when you can use what the standard library already provides.

Comment: @Lapys Do you really need to?  If you want a standard conformant `vector` it is quite a bit of code.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the inner workings of C++ through my own practice and research, folks.

Comment: @Lapys You can see a good bit of it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60484/stl-vector-implementation).  There is also some more [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138389/my-own-stdvector).  I also believe one of Bjarne Stroustrup's books also details how to make a vector.

Comment: @NathanOliver as a matter of fact, `std::vector` is one of the simpler STL constructs, and creating one from the scratch is not really challenging. Just follow standard and implement all required interfaces and constraints. Efficient `std::variant`, on the other hand, is something more interesting.

Comment: @SergeyA I never said it was challenging, I just said it is a bit of code.  It's probably one of the best containers to start with though, as it introduces a lot of concepts all of the library uses.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't really argue with you, just commented in addition. I also think that implementing `std::vector` is a good learning exercise, which introduces student to lot of concepts without really challenging them to something which could be hard to implement.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont it is possible, but you need to be willing to step in the undefined behavior territory :D

Comment: @SergeyA Sure, but then `*(char const**)nullptr = "compiler write a vector for me please";` is also a fully working std vector, depending on what the UB does.  UB does *anything*.  And there is no way to implement a std vector in C++ without the implementation invoking UB.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am aware of this, but if you are implementing a vector, you are taking the role of implementation yourself. So there is no undefined behavior for you, there is just currently happening implementation-defined behavior.